# How do i create a javascript that loops through an array of images on mouse hover over

Tags: javascript, image, loops

I have an image like the following

```
coolimg.1.jpg
```

I would like to loop the `1` with the following array:

```
[2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29]
```

...on `mouseover` with a delay for 1 second

How should I get started?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ ?

Comment: send me da codez yesterday pleez!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

This will animate the element with the id in `imgId`. The animation only starts after 1 second on `mouseover`.

**HTML**

```
<img id="myImg" onmouseover="imgId = this.id; timer = setTimeout(animate, 1000);" onmouseout="stopAnimation();" src="coolimg.1.jpg" />
```

**JS**

```
var myImages = [1, 2, 3, 5]
var img_index = 0;
var timer;
var imgId = "myImg";

// Start animation
function animate() {
    me = document.getElementById(imgId);

    me.src = "coolimg." + myImages[img_index] + ".jpg"

    img_index++;

    if (img_index == myImages.length){
        img_index = 0;
    }

    timer = setTimeout(animate, 1000);
}

function stopAnimation() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: how can i pass the img id to a variable on mouseover so that i can use this neat script on multiple images on one page?

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgs  = [2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29]
  , last  = imgs.length
  , count = 0
  , timer
  , img_name
;//var

function cycleImage(){
  if(count++ < last){
    img_name = 'coolimg.' + imgs[count] + '.jpg';
    // do something with image
    timer = setTimeout(changeImage, 1000);
  }
}

function resetImage(){
  count = 0;
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

var $element = $('element');

$element
  .on ('mouseover', cycleImage)
  .off('mouseout' , resetImage)
;//var
```

Comment: What if you get multiple mouseover events before the looping is done and generally you should not propose jQuery when that is not indicated in the question.

Comment: I make that assumption because you have to normalize the event binding somehow. I could have written the entire function to do that and given him cross browser compatibility, but I don't see a point when jQuery dominates the landscape and is cached on a significant number of computers. Besides, there were no requirements made for the solution, I'm free to use any implementation I like.

Comment: You will obviously get race conditions when the animation is played multiple times, but until I know exactly what the goal is, I can't assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is by far not complete but it could give a place to start:

```
var imageRoller=function(){
    this.myNumbers=[2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29];
    this.currentIndex=0;
    this.timerID=0;
    this.onMouseover=function(){
        //do something
        var currentID="coolimg."+
            this.myNumbers[this.currentIndex]+
            ".jpg";
        //increase the current index
        this.currentIndex++;
        if(this.currentIndex>=
            this.myNumbers.length){
            this.myNumbers=0;
        }
        //do something again in 1 second
        me=this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            me.onMouseover();
        },1000);
    }
    this.onMouseout=function(){
        // stop doing something agqain in 1 second
        clearTimeout(this.timerID);
    }
    //attach the mouseover and out events:
    var me = this;
    document.getElementById("someImg")
        .addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            me.onMouseover.call(me);
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This version has better separation of code and markup:

```
        var coolimg = {
            images      : [2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29],
            position    : 0,
            mouseOver   : false,
            target      : document.getElementById('coolimg')
        }

        coolimg.target.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
            coolimg.mouseOver = true;
        });
        coolimg.target.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
            coolimg.mouseOver = false;
        });

        setInterval(function(){
            if (coolimg.mouseOver) {
                coolimg.position = (coolimg.position+1)%coolimg.images.length;
                coolimg.target.src = 'coolimg.'+coolimg.images[coolimg.position]+'.jpg';
            }
        }, 1000);
```